# Why right-hand gutter marker in eclipse for mac doesn't show?

Tags: eclipse, macos, user-interface, ide, appearance

I was trying to use Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Indigo and configure different colors for occurences in preferences but the marker doesn't show up in right hand gutter for occurences and errors as it should. By any chance do yo know how to rectify such annoying problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .properties file I had to set the following natures:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo.BeanInfoNature</nature>
```

to the following:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature</nature>
</natures>
```

That solves the problem!

Comment: Can you edit your question to tell us where this .properties file reside. I can not seem to find it in my eclipse install. Thanks.

Comment: I believe 'natures' is usually in the .project file, not .properties, however, mine were correct but i still have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Lion (10.7) then ensure you set Apple -> Settings -> General -> Show Scroll Bars to "When Scrolling". This is the only option that works.